# Switch support in API 15

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-switch

I am currently using the [Switch Widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) which supposedly came in API 14.  My project is set to a min API of 15.  I am trying to change the background of the Switch widget track `OnCheckedChanged`

but i get an error that setTrackResource needs a minimum API of 16..  I thought at first i just needed to update my support library but its on v13

I don't want to @supress this warning?  is there a way around it?

```
cameraTypeSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.cameraTypeSwitch);
        cameraTypeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (buttonView.isChecked()){
                    cameraTypeSwitch.setTrackResource(R.drawable.camera_track_camera);
                }
                else{
                    cameraTypeSwitch.setTrackResource(R.drawable.camera_track_video);
                }
            }
    });
```

i tried to set the track drawable to have an on checked state like so:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@null" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_track_camera" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/camera_track_video" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.. is there anyway to dynamically change the track background in  API 15

Comment: What is your API build target? It should be at least 16.

Answer (score 2):

From [Android official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setTrackResource%28int%29)

> public void setTrackResource (int resId) **Added in API level 16**

So you need API 16+ to use `setTrackResource(int)` method (that is, minSDK should be 16 or higher). There's no workaround since this method doesn't exist in API 15 or less, unless you write it yourself.

Comment: That said, anyway in my selector xml file for the track to set the drawable based on which state its in?

Comment: I don't understand your question